# How to find a smallest value without trying all posibilities

Tags: math, lua

I am trying to write a program (in Lua, but I guess this is more of a mathematical problem) that calculates the total distance between a set of numbers and there are two or three different possibilities for some of these numbers.

For example a set of numbers is: 2, 5, 0, 1. The sum of distances in this case is 9. (5-2 + 5-0 + 1-0)
The first row with alternatives is: 5, -, 3, 2.
The second row with alternatives is: 3, -, -, 3
The combination between the two rows with the smallest sum of distances is: 5, 5, 3, 3 with a sum of distances of 2.

My first attempt was to write a program that tries all possible iterations, but with a set of about 40 numbers, there are so many possibilities that my computer crashed...

Here is the code for that version, it first creates all the different possibilities and then calculates the differences and places them in column 0. Afterwards I can find the smallest value easily and see also the combination of numbers which results in that value.

```lua
local table1 = {2, 5, 0 ,1}
local table2 = {5, nil, 3, 2}
local imax = 1
local solution = {}
local answer = table1[1]

for x = 1,#table1 do
    solution[x]={}
    for i= 1, (2^imax)/2 do
        solution[x][i] = table1[x]
    end
    if table2[x] ~= nil then -- there is an alternative number
        for y = 1, x-1 do -- copy all the previous table entries except the last one
            for j = ((2^imax)/2)+1, 2^imax do -- the number of new rows increases exponentially
                solution[y][j] = solution[y][j-imax]
            end
        end
        for j = ((2^imax)/2)+1, 2^imax do -- create the new table entry with the alternative number
            solution[x][j] = table2[x]
        end
        imax = imax + 1 -- this number is to remind how many alternative numbers where found
    end
end

solution[0]={}
for x = 1, #table1 do
    for i = 1, (2^imax)/2 do
        if x < #table1 then answer = math.sqrt((solution[x+1][i]-solution[x][i])^2) else answer = 0 end
        if solution[0][i] == nil then solution[0][i] = answer else solution[0][i] = solution[0][i] + answer end
    end
end
```

After reading about dynamic programming, I wrote a new version of this program. It calculates the smallest sum of differences, but I also want to know the path (the combination of numbers) to that sum... Still work to do...

```lua
local table1 = {2, 5, 0 ,1}
local table2 = {5, nil, 3, 2}
local solution = {}
local smallestsolution = {}
solution[1]={}
solution[2]={}
solution[3]={}
solution[4]={}

for i = 1, (#table1-1) do
    solution[1][i] = math.sqrt((table1[i+1]-table1[i])^2)
    if table2[i] ~= nil then solution[2][i] = math.sqrt((table1[i+1]-table2[i])^2) end
    if table2[i+1] ~= nil then solution[3][i] = math.sqrt((table2[i+1]-table1[i])^2) end
    if table2[i] ~= nil and table2[i+1] ~= nil then solution[4][i] = math.sqrt((table2[i+1]-table2[i])^2) end
end

for i = 1, (#table1-1) do
    smallestsolution[i]=100000
    for j = 1, 4 do
        if solution[j][i] ~= nil and solution[j][i] < smallestsolution[i] then smallestsolution[i]=solution[j][i] end
    end
end

local smallestsum = 0
for i = 1, (#table1-1) do
    smallestsum = smallestsum + smallestsolution[i]
end
```

Thanks,

Emile

Comment: Hi! Would you please consider rephrasing the second paragraph? I cannot understand it.

Comment: Dynamic programming solves this task instantly, assuming you have 40 numbers and 40 variants for each number.

Comment: @Stef: Sorry if I was not clear! I want to calculate the difference between all the sets of numbers in row. For instance with the row 2, 5, 0, 1. The difference between 2 and 5 is 3, the difference between 5 and 0 is 5 etc. The sum of all these differences is 9.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Thanks for the suggestion. I have more or less 40 numbers, it changes per case and there are 0, 1 or 2 variants per number. I am not familiar with dynamic programming, but just googled it and at first glance it seems that it will do the trick. I will go and study it! Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the code from your attempt to the question?

Comment: @Emile By "difference between all the sets of numbers in row" you mean "differences between adjacent pairs of numbers" or "differences between all possible n(n-1)/2 pairs?
Also, you want the absolute value of the difference?

Comment: @Nifim I have updated my question with my original code.

Comment: @Alexander Mashin: I mean the absolute differences between adjacent pairs of numbers. What I want to calculate is sqrt(x[n+1]-x[n])^2) where x is the table with numbers, and n the position. I want to know the sum of this equation for n=1 to the number of elements of the table. And there is a table with alternative numbers (let's call it y). I want to know the smallest sum possible and which combination of numbers leads to that sum.

Comment: @Emile is that sum of squares cyclical, i.e., does it include `(x[#x], x[0])^2`?

And now to the second table: is the distance calculated between (`t1[n]` or `t2[n]`) and (`t1[n+1]` or `t2[n+1]`), whichever of the four combinations will give the smallest result?

And if `t2[n+1]` was chosen, should it be also chosen as the first element of the next pair: `t2[n+1]` and `t1[n+2]` or `t2[n+2]`?

Comment: @AlexanderMashin I'm not sure if I understand you... I have added some code up which works to calculate the smallest sum. I guess that clarifies more than I can write here...

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it myself! The hint to dynamic programming by @EgorSkriptunoff did the trick!

```
local table1 = {2, 5, 0 ,1}
local table2 = {5, nil, 3, 2}
local solution = {}
local smallestsolution = {}
solution[1]={}
solution[2]={}
solution[3]={}
solution[4]={}
local path = {}
local temp = {}

for i = 1, (#table1-1) do
    solution[1][i] = math.sqrt((table1[i+1]-table1[i])^2)
    if table2[i] ~= nil then solution[2][i] = math.sqrt((table1[i+1]-table2[i])^2) end
    if table2[i+1] ~= nil then solution[3][i] = math.sqrt((table2[i+1]-table1[i])^2) end
    if table2[i] ~= nil and table2[i+1] ~= nil then solution[4][i] = math.sqrt((table2[i+1]-table2[i])^2) end
end

for i = 1, (#table1-1) do
    smallestsolution[i]=100000
    temp[i] = 0
    for j = 1, 4 do
        if solution[j][i] ~= nil and solution[j][i] < smallestsolution[i] then smallestsolution[i]=solution[j][i] temp[i] = j end
    end
end

local smallestsum = 0
for i = 1, (#table1-1) do
    smallestsum = smallestsum + smallestsolution[i]
end

for i = 1, (#table1) do -- find the path belonging to the smallest sum of differences
    if temp[i] == 1 then path[i] = table1[i] end
    if temp[i] == 2 then path[i] = table2[i] end
    if temp[i] == 3 then path[i] = table1[i] end
    if temp[i] == 4 then path[i] = table2[i] end
    if i == (#table1) then
        if temp[i-1] == 1 then path[i] = table1[i] end
        if temp[i-1] == 2 then path[i] = table1[i] end
        if temp[i-1] == 3 then path[i] = table2[i] end
        if temp[i-1] == 4 then path[i] = table2[i] end
    end
end
```